# Access object property

Tags: javascript

How i can select the `count(user)` from the `tab` object?

```
var tab =
[
    { id: '1', 'count(user)': 11 },
    { id: '2', 'count(user)': 31 },
    { id: '3', 'count(user)': 3 }
]
```

This prints `2`:

```
console.log(tab[1].id)
```

but this gives me an error:

```
console.log(tab[1].count(user))
```

> ReferenceError: user is not defined

How can I fix this?

Comment: tab[1]['count(user)']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
alert(tab[1]["count(user)"]);
```

Here is an example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxo5j1ee/)

By the way, while the JSON in your example technically works, it is not formatted in a "best practice" way. Parameter names should have quotes around them:

```
{ 'id': '1',...
```

And parameter names should be [valid JavaScript variables names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/579148), ie., no parenthesis, brackets, etc. This would be a more acceptable name:

```
'count_user': 11
```

Then you would not have had an issue using

```
console.log(tab[1].count_user)
```